# How to do Apple Diagnostics on Macbook pro with a dead screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have a 2016 MacBook Pro running Sierra and the screen has gone black.  I'm using my HDTV now for an external monitor.  I want to do a diagnostics test to find out what to fix.  But the external monitor doesn't work when I try to run the diagnostics, so I can't see the results.  Also screen sharing works but not when I try to run diagnostics.  I have tried holding D key at startup and also Option-D.  I have tried SNC reset, PRAM reset, booting from an external drive, all the usual.  Does anyone have a workaround?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This may not work in diagnostics recovery mode, but its worth a try.

After booting into diagnostics mode with the D key at boot, try pressing Command and F5 keys, to activate voicover utility. Then, navigate the utility using voiceover.

Comment: Well, I never would have thought of that one!  Worth a try, as you say.  Thanks, Dan!

Comment: I tried to activate the voiceover thing, but on the diagnostics run, the touch strip doesn't illuminate!  Oh well...